# Evaluating enum in switch

Tags: java, enums

```
enum type {WD, AGGT, ACCT}
public type empType



public void salary(int choice, int hours_Worked)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
        case ?:  
        case ?: 
        case ?:
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what to put in the cases as the choice that's being passed into the methods are numeric, most examples I find are all string comparisons.. I could always just force the cases to be one and two but... that would kill the point of having the enum in the first place..

Comment: You define an enum `type`.But your example is unclear what you want to do with it. And how are `type` and `choice` related?

Answer (score 2):

Really, the method should take a `type choice`, not `int choice`, as argument. (And, `Type` really should be capitalized and given a better name.)

Are you asking how to get from an ordinal integer value to an enum value? It's not really a good idea, but if you must, you can convert this way:

```
type valueOf(int ordinal) {
  for (type t : type.values()) {
    if (t.ordinal() == ordinal) {
      return t;
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

... but again, this is fixing bad design. Change that method.

Comment: hmm I see I was thinking it was kind of bad guess I'll change the method thanks.

Comment: You might consider the type.values() method you get for free with enums.  You can now implement this method in one line: return type.values()[ordinal];  and this will throw a runtime exception (IndexOutOfBounds) if ordinal is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

First an enum in Java is declared in the following way:

```
public enum EmpType {
    WD, AGGT, ACCT
}
```

The enum name should be upper case by convention. To refer to an enum value simply qualify it, such as `EmpType.WD`. However inside a switch, it's inferred, so you've to omit it, for instance:

```
EmpType myEmpType = EmpType.WD;
switch (myEmpType) {
    case WD:
          break;
    default:
}
```

Notice that the variable type is declared as `EmpType`, not int. Take a look at the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Take a look to the tutorial too, I've added the link in my post.

Answer (score 0):

The method should look like this:

```
public void salary(Type choice, int hours_Worked)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
        case WD:  
        case ACCT: 
        case AGGT:
        }
    }
```

because IF you have an enum you shoul use it and not some anonymous `int`
If you really must you can convert the ordinal (which is an implementation detail) this way:

```
Type type = Type..... // WD, ...
int o = type.ordinal();
// reverse mapping: ordinal -> Type
Type type2 = Type.values()[o];
```